# Java, trying to compile, get following error message, what does this mean?

Tags: java, linux

Alright so when I try to compile this in java, I get the following error message

error: Class names, 'TokenTest', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error

What does this mean and how can I fix it? I've tried numerous things but cant understand what it is referring to. Thanks for your help! Does this mean I need to change the name so it isn't TokenTest?

```
 import java.io.*;

  import java.util.*;

  class TokenTest {

     public static void main (String[] args) {
        TokenTest tt = new TokenTest();
        tt.dbTest();
     }
     void dbTest() {

        DataInputStream dis = null;
        String dbRecord = null;

        try {

           File f = new File("sales.info");
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
           dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

           // read the first record of the database
           while ( (dbRecord = dis.readLine()) != null) {

              StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(dbRecord, ",");
              String fname = st.nextToken();
              String lname = st.nextToken();
              String city  = st.nextToken();
              String state = st.nextToken();

              System.out.println("First Name:  " + fname);
              System.out.println("Last Name:   " + lname);
              System.out.println("City:        " + city);
              System.out.println("State:       " + state + "\n");
           }
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // catch io errors from FileInputStream or readLine()
           System.out.println("Uh oh, got an IOException error!" + e.getMessage());

        } finally {
           // if the file opened okay, make sure we close it
           if (dis != null) {
              try {
                 dis.close();
              } catch (IOException ioe) {
              }
           }//  end if
        }// end finally
     } // end dbTest
  } // end class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [link about common problems when compiling Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/):

> `Class names, 'HelloWorldApp', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`
>
> If you receive this error, you forgot to include the `.java` suffix when compiling the program. Remember, the command is `javac HelloWorldApp.java` not `javac HelloWorldApp`.

After fixing the error, you would get a warning about the use of a deprecated method in the following line:

```
while ((dbRecord = dis.readLine()) != null) {
```

This is because `DataInputStream#readLine` is deprecated. See [the class Javadoc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) to know why it is deprecated and which API to use instead.

Comment: Note: TokenTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: when I do that, I get the following message

Comment: Worth pointing out that if you take the error text and Google for it, this page is the first result...

Comment: @Michael for you new problem, did you recompile with -Xlint:deprecation ?

Comment: No I did not, never knew about it til now.  Like this?  javac -Xlint TokenTest.java

Answer (score 3):

If you receive this error, you forgot to include the .java suffix when compiling the program.